# Only a limited amount of pins are being displayed in mobile device compared to PC

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, pins

I am loading a map view. And I am adding pins to the map, based on address of the contacts in address book. I am having some strange cases where some pins(maybe 2 out of 10) don't drop in the map view . I have checked the address, which is valid. But the pin is not dropping. What could be the reason for this.

```
    for (i = 0; i<[groupContentArray count]; i++) {
        person = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressbook,[[groupContentArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue]);
        ABMultiValueRef addressProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty);
        NSArray *address = (NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(addressProperty);
        NSLog(@"Address %@", address);
        for (NSDictionary *addressDict in address) 
        {
            addAnnotation = nil;
            firstName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty); 
            lastName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty); 

            NSString *country = [addressDict objectForKey:@"Country"];
            NSString *streetName = [addressDict objectForKey:@"Street"];
            NSString *cityName = [addressDict objectForKey:@"City"];
            NSString *stateName = [addressDict objectForKey:@"State"];

            if (streetName == (id)[NSNull null] || streetName.length == 0 ) streetName = @"";
            if (stateName == (id)[NSNull null] || stateName.length == 0 ) stateName = @"";
            if (cityName == (id)[NSNull null] || cityName.length == 0 ) cityName = @"";
            if (country == (id)[NSNull null] || country.length == 0 ) country = @"";


            NSString *fullAddress = [streetName stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", cityName, stateName, country];
            mapCenter = [self getLocationFromAddressString:fullAddress];
            if(stateName != NULL || country != NULL || streetName != NULL || cityName != NULL){

                if ((mapCenter.latitude == 0) && (mapCenter.longitude == 0))
                {
                    // Alert View
                }
                else{
                addAnnotation = (MyAddressAnnotation *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:[groupContentArray objectAtIndex:i]];

                if(addAnnotation == nil){
                    addAnnotation = [[[MyAddressAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:mapCenter title:firstName SubTitle:lastName Recordid:[groupContentArray objectAtIndex:i] ]autorelease];

                    [mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation];}
                                    }
            }
        }
        CFRelease(addressProperty);

    }
```

Edit: I am editing my question and be more specific. I am using the code to drop pins on my mapView. On my Mac PC, if there are 20 pins to be dropped in the map. All the 20 pins are dropping accurately and working fine. But when I am using IPhone or IPad, the pin count reduces massively. That is, out of some 20 pins I am dropping, only 4 pins are showing on the map. I am not able to figure out a reason for this.

Comment: Can you please show some part of coding ?

Comment: Without any of your code I'm pretty sure it's impossible to say what is wrong. In other words: please provide some more information such as code.

Comment: Completely agree with Hadley...please provide what u have coded..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. In the "fulladdress" string(between streetName and cityName) that I use, were not separated by a space or "," or "/". Therefore some of the addresses were not being recognised.

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
else {
    addAnnotation = (MyAddressAnnotation *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:[groupContentArray objectAtIndex:i]];

    if (addAnnotation == nil) {
        addAnnotation = [[[MyAddressAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:mapCenter title:firstName SubTitle:lastName Recordid:[groupContentArray objectAtIndex:i] ]autorelease];

        [mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation];
    }
}
```

makes no sense.

The `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier` method is for dequeuing `MKAnnotationView` objects -- not `id<MKAnnotation>` objects.

The dequeuing code belongs in the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method anyway, not here.

Here, you should just create your annotation objects (`MyAddressAnnotation`) and call `addAnnotation` on them.

I also highly recommend you change the name of your annotation variable from `addAnnotation` to something else so you can't confuse it with the map view's method `addAnnotation`.

Comment: Is there any thing I can do to make the map load faster. Right now it is too slow to load.